# Как сделать валидацию формы регистрации на JSX?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

Всем привет, учу React с JSX, пытаюсь сделать валидацию формы регистрации для имени и фамилии. Нужно, чтобы если поле или поля ввода состояли только из пробелов или невидимых символом (ㅤ), то подсвечивались красным при нажатии на кнопку "Далее". Ну а эта кнопка, соответственно, не выполняла действие `next` до тех пор, пока поля не пройдут валидацию.

Пытался сам сделать, только для проверки на пустоту input`ов, но работает она максимально некорректно: два поля пусты, подсвечивается только surname, а name, если ввести 1 символ в него. В общем, спасайте. Заранее спасибо.

JSX:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [nameInvalid, setNameInvalid] = useState(false);
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');
  const [surnameInvalid, setSurnameInvalid] = useState(false);
  
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    if (!name) {
      setNameInvalid(true);
      return;
    }
  
    if (!surname) {
      setSurnameInvalid(true);
      return;
    }

  }


          <form on onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <label htmlFor="username"></label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="username"
                className={`InputForm ${nameInvalid ? 'invalid' : ''}`}
                placeholder="Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setName(e.target.value);
                  setNameInvalid(name.trim() === '');
                }}
                required
                onInvalid={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  setNameInvalid(true);
                }}
              />

              <label htmlFor="usersurname"></label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="usersurname"
                className={`InputForm ${surnameInvalid ? 'invalid' : ''}`}
                placeholder="Surname"
                value={surname}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setSurname(e.target.value);

                  setNameInvalid(surname.trim() === '');
                }}
                required
                onInvalid={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  setNameInvalid(true);
                }}
              />

            <button
              className='RegisterButton'
              type="button"
              onClick={(e) => {
                if (!surname) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  setSurnameInvalid(true);
                  return;
                }
                handleStepChange("next");
              }}
            >Далее</button>

          </form>
```

CSS:

```
.InputForm.invalid {
  outline: 2px solid #fa05a0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для валидации и подсветки невалидных инпутов, можно изменить код так:

```
function checkValues(val) {
  return !!!val.trim();
}

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [nameInvalid, setNameInvalid] = useState(false);
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState("");
  const [surnameInvalid, setSurnameInvalid] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    let flag = true; // флаг возможности отправки
    if (!checkValues(name)) {
      setNameInvalid(false);
      flag = true;
    } else {
      setNameInvalid(true);
    }

    if (!checkValues(surname)) {
      setSurnameInvalid(false);
      flag = true;
    } else {
      setSurnameInvalid(true);
    }

    if (flag) {
      fetch("someUrs", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, surname })
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="username"></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="username"
        className={`InputForm ${nameInvalid ? "invalid" : ""}`}
        placeholder="Name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
        required
      />

      <label htmlFor="usersurname"></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="usersurname"
        className={`InputForm ${surnameInvalid ? "invalid" : ""}`}
        placeholder="Surname"
        value={surname}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSurname(e.target.value);
        }}
        required
      />

      <button className="RegisterButton" type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Далее
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Функция `checkValues` указана в качестве примера. Вы можете использовать свою для проверки введенных значений.

Так же, рекомендую отказаться от form в реакт проектах. Для передачи данных на сервер используйте fetch(), например.

Comment: Тестировал [в песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-panka-wqz68y?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я хотел бы уточнить, зачем в выражении return !!!val.trim(); использовать "!!!", а не просто "!"? Это же ведь отрицание отрицания и отрицание положительного, что в итоге дает отрицание.  Я уже перешерстил пособия по тернарным операторам, но, честно говоря, не особо понял данный финт.)

Comment: Так же вопрос, мне нужно реализовать при удачной валидации переход к след этапу. Раньше у меня в кнопке было handleStepChange("next");, а сейчас handleSubmit, можно ли эти две функции определить для одной кнопки? Только, я так понимаю, нужно прописать еще логику под handleStepChange("next"); типа , если flag положительный, то разрешить действие handleStepChange("next");? PS я написал, теперь, независимо от валидации, действие "Далее" выполняется. Какую логику нужно использовать, чтобы переход был возможен ТОЛЬКО после выполнения валидации?

Comment: Посмотрел, !!! Лишнее. Надо заменить на !! А в if убрать !. В примере(ответе) не тега form, поэтому ничего по кнопке не должно происходить того, что не определено в функции `handleSubmit`. Если надо вызвать другую функцию, при успешной валидации, поместите ее в `if (flag)`